# Delete Registered App in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-addin, app, azure-active-directory

I registered an SharePoint Add-in using `...pwa/_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx` but I did a writing error on the `Redirect URI` and because of this reason, my Add-in is not working.

Is there an Page ware I can manage my registered apps or what is the best solution for this Problem?

Comment: hey my friend, I have added an answer that I think will help you. Please check it out =)

Answer (score 7):

You can go to the following link and delete your app and permission from here

```
siteURL/_layouts/15/appprincipals.aspx?Scope=Web
```

You find all your registered app here.

Answer (score 4):

All the answers on this post so far are related on **how to delete a sp addin app instance from a site**, however, what you are looking for is how to **edit or remove** a **sharepoint addin application** config/registration, that has been created from `/_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx`.

*Sharepoint online:*

- You will need to go to your **o365 admin portal**.
- Click on the **Azure Active Directory portal**.
- Search for the **Enterprise Applications** => **All applications**.
- Filter by **All applications** and by your **sp addin Id**.

Once in the settings, you can change them or just delete it. Here is a screenshot that may help you :)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to SharePoint site contents and return to classic experience (if in SharePoint Online)

1. Right click on the app
2. Click "Remove"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the following URL `http://.../_layouts/15/AppInv.aspx`  and on this page you can get the info for your App details.

On the following Link `_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx` you can update the settings.

Check this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863574/how-to-unregister-or-update-registered-sharepoint-app

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a9a738b1-7936-4446-9a1c-493ec4b7d618/how-to-unregister-or-update-registered-sharepoint-app?forum=appsforsharepoint

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can safely create new one with valid redirect uri, you can even have many applications pointed to the same redirect uri.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me: Deleting the app per powershell
Original poster: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36549952/6445723

Here are the steps as they have change since that post:

1. Get the AzureAD PowerShell module - As Administrator run Install-Module -Name AzureAD
2. Open a new PowerShell window and type Connect-AzureAD and login using your credentials (include @onmicrosoft.com or whatever custom domain you are using)
3. Run Get-AzureADServicePrincipal and find your App name among the list. Copy the ObjectId
4. Remove-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId [your-app-id]

Done, the app is gone and you can register a new one. In SharePoint Online it seems to be the only working solution.